# Trouble plotting an ImplicitRegion

Tags: regions

I have an implicit region:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[-Sqrt[-1 + 1/4 (x + 1/(x + I y) + I y)^2] + 
   1/2 (x + 1/(x + I y) + I y) == x + I y, {x, y}]
```

I tried plotting it with `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[R, PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}]
```

but got an error message,

> RegionPlot::invplotreg: {ImplicitRegion[-Sqrt[-1+Times[<<2>>]]+1/2 (x+1/Plus[<<2>>]+I y)==x+I y,{x,y}]} is not a valid region to plot. >>

Manually executing `RegionPlot` seems to work:

```
RegionPlot[-Sqrt[-1 + 1/4 (x + 1/(x + I y) + I y)^2] + 
   1/2 (x + 1/(x + I y) + I y) == x + I y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

which produces

[image]

Similarly, I tried to discretize the region:

```
DiscretizeRegion[R, {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}]
```

but got an error message:

> DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion[<<2>>]. >>

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong?

### Edit

Algohi has suggested that the problem might have to do with the fact that the truth statement is an equality of complex quantities, which might confuse `ImplicitRegion` into thinking that it's dummy variables are meant to be taken over the complex numbers, which contradicts the Documentation's stipulation that the values are in $\mathbb R^n$. Unfortunately, this is not the case, as the following counterexample shows:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[y + I x == y - I x, {x, y}]
RegionPlot[R]
```

which correctly produces:

[image]

Comment: To the downvoter: what part of my question was unclear? I would appreciate feedback if my question needs to be reworked.

Comment: I don't think your lase example is a valid one. y + I x == y - I x // Simplify results in x == 0. Try some example where  (I) can't be factored out.

Comment: @Algohi: Hmm, trying some other nontrivial examples gives errors. Still, it makes no sense. My expression is a well-defined map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\{0,1\}$. The fact that the internal arithmetic uses complex numbers does not alter the function signature, which is a map of the real plane to truth values, so I can't understand why `ImplicitRegion` cannot handle it.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the problem stands in `ImplicitRegion`. A workaround is to use `Reduce` as done below. Also, you should impose explicitly that x and y are Reals.

```
R = Reduce[-Sqrt[-1 + 1/4 (x + 1/(x + I y) + I y)^2] + 1/2 (x + 1/(x + I y) + I y) == x + I y && x \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals, {x, y}]
RegionPlot[R, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about this but it looks like `ImplicitRegion` works only with real domain.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the plotting region I have used is real-valued (see the examples I provided). It is only the expression itself that is complex-valued (or rather, it is boolean-valued, but is an equality of complex expressions); the variables `x` and `y` are being plotted over a real region, so I'm not sure this answers my question.

Comment: I don't understand when you say your region is real valued. I see an imaginary number (I) in you expression.

Comment: No, the region is real-valued; the expression is Boolean-valued and is comprised of an `Equal` statement which contains an `I` in one of it's sub-branches. That does not make the region real-valued. As further proof, I appended a counterexample to my question, which shows that `ImplicitRegion` is capable of handling complex-valued expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
ℛ = -Sqrt[-1 + 1/4 (x + 1/(x + I y) + I y)^2] + 
   1/2 (x + 1/(x + I y) + I y) == x + I y
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot[ℛ, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused. OP already showed this can be done.

Comment: Yeah, I already showed that a direct application of `RegionPlot` on the expression works properly in my question, but that's not what my question was asking. My question was twofold: why does `RegionPlot` fail on the equivalent `ImplicitRegion`, and why does `DiscretizeRegion` also fail on the `ImplicitRegion`?

Comment: @RunnyKine: Any idea what my problem could be? My question seems to be getting downvoted, and I'm not sure if I've just done something silly.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus. Your question is perfectly valid. The only thing I can say is `ImplicitRegion` is not ready for primetime. I've experienced a lot of problems with it.